# Communicate through TextWriter -> TextReader

Tags: c#, .net

One way to have interprocess communication is through a (named) pipe between the processes.

I want to achive the same "queue"-like communication between two threads. The producer should write a text base command (using TextWriter or an output Stream).
The consumer should read from the TextReader. Because, then you think about it, an OutputStream/-Writer is the other side of the coin of an InputStream/-Reader. So using a Writer to fill a Reader with data, that should be easy, in theory.

(The standard way here is to have a Queue between the threads. However I wish to use TextReader and TextWriter, since I have existing code for front and backends already. This way it will be easy to debug by connecting the Console.In / Console.Out to the producer/consumer. )

I thought this would be really easy to just connect a writer to a reader, but I fail to find out how to do it.

I could write one such connected myself, but it feels like it "should" already be there.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Leif

Comment: you can just create an thread safe queue that can fire event on adding and deleting from queue, and put in queue in one thread and take in another, there is many ways to do what you want, so please explain your requirements in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up finding a "ready-made" solution. I wrote my own.
A new class ThroughputStream, which in it's Write-end receives data, posts them through a thread safe queue to the Read-end which uses the received data-chunks to Read from.

```
namespace My.IO
{
    public class ThrouputStream 
    {
        private InputStreamClass inputStream;
        private OutputStreamClass outputStream;

        private Queue<byte[]> queue = new Queue<byte[]>();
        private System.Threading.EventWaitHandle queueEvent = new System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(false, System.Threading.EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        public ThrouputStream()
        {
            inputStream = new InputStreamClass(this);
            outputStream = new OutputStreamClass(this);
        }

        public Stream InputStream
        {
            get { return inputStream; }
        }

        public Stream OutputStream
        {
            get { return outputStream; }
        }

        private class InputStreamClass : Stream
        {
            private readonly Queue<byte[]> queue;
            private readonly ThrouputStream parent;
            private byte[] currentBlock = null;
            private int currentBlockPos = 0;
            private Boolean closed = false;
            private int readTimeoutMs = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

            public InputStreamClass(ThrouputStream parent)
            {

                this.parent = parent;
                this.queue = parent.queue;
            }

            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override bool CanSeek
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override bool CanWrite
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override void Flush()
            {
                // Do nothing, always flushes.
            }

            public override long Length
            {
                get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            }

            public override long Position
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                set
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }

            public override bool CanTimeout
            {
                get
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public override int ReadTimeout
            {
                get
                {
                    return readTimeoutMs;
                }
                set
                {
                    readTimeoutMs = value;
                }
            }

            public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                if (currentBlock == null)
                {
                    int queueCount;
                    lock (queue)
                    {
                        queueCount = queue.Count;
                        if ( queueCount > 0 )
                            currentBlock = queue.Dequeue();
                    }

                    if (currentBlock == null && !parent.outputStream.IsClosed )
                    {
                        parent.queueEvent.WaitOne(readTimeoutMs);

                        lock (queue)
                        {
                            if (queue.Count == 0)
                                return 0;

                            currentBlock = queue.Dequeue();
                        }
                    }

                    currentBlockPos = 0;
                }

                if (currentBlock == null)
                    return 0;

                int read = Math.Min(count, currentBlock.Length - currentBlockPos);
                Array.Copy(currentBlock, currentBlockPos, buffer, offset, read);
                currentBlockPos += read;
                if (currentBlockPos == currentBlock.Length)
                {
                    // did read whole block
                    currentBlockPos = 0;
                    currentBlock = null;
                }

                return read;
            }

            public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void SetLength(long value)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void Close()
            {
                this.closed = true;
                base.Close();
            }
        }

        private class OutputStreamClass : Stream
        {
            private bool isClosed = false;

            private readonly Queue<byte[]> queue;
            private readonly ThrouputStream parent;

            public OutputStreamClass(ThrouputStream parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
                this.queue = parent.queue;
            }

            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override bool CanSeek
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            public override bool CanWrite
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            public override void Flush()
            {
                // always flush
            }

            public override long Length
            {
                get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            }

            public override long Position
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                set
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }

            public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            public override void SetLength(long value)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                byte[] copy = new byte[count];
                Array.Copy(buffer, offset, copy, 0, count);
                lock (queue)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(copy);
                    try
                    {
                        parent.queueEvent.Set();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { }
                }
            }

            public override void Close()
            {
                this.isClosed = true;
                base.Close();

                // Signal event, to stop waiting consumer
                try
                {
                    parent.queueEvent.Set();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }

            public bool IsClosed
            {
                get { return isClosed; }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would discourage the use of streams and TextWriter/TextReader as an effective means of communication between threads. You would need to have one stream for each "queue", and to ensure valid data is fully written or read, you would need to lock that stream for each write or read operation. A better solution would probably be something like so:

Set up a Queue of type string, along with a couple ManualResetEvents. The general idea would be to use thread signaling to allow two threads to communicate without the need for a lock.

```
public static class ThreadTest
{
    public void Main()
    {
        long exit = 0;

        Queue<string> messages = new Queue<string>();
        ManualResetEvent signal1 = new ManualResetEvent();
        ManualResetEvent signal2 = new ManualResetEvent();

        signal2.Set();

        Thread writer = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (exit == 0)
            {
                string value = Console.ReadLine();
                if (value == "exit")
                {
                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref exit, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    messages.Enqueue(value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Written: " + value);
                    signal1.Set();
                }

                signal2.WaitOne();
            }
        });

        Thread reader = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (exit == 0)
            {
                signal1.WaitOne();
                signal2.Reset();

                value = messages.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine("Read: " + value);

                signal2.Set();
                signal1.Reset();
            }
        });

        reader.Start();
        writer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree in full!
Using a stream to communicate between two threads is generally a bad idea.
For my experiment I had the intension of using it to "unit-test" existing code which is the base a console program.